# Bash: how do I pipe the output of every command through "less --quit-if-one-screen"?

Tags: bash, less, pager

When I run some commands in Bash, I have no idea how many number of lines the output will be. If the number of lines in the output exceeds the height of my terminal, I will not be able to see the output at the beginning. To see what I have missed, I will have to run the command again, and pipe it through `less` in order to see the full output. Recently, I discovered `less --quit-if-one-screen` (`less -F`). I have gotten into a habit of piping the output of commands into `less -F` in order to not miss any output. Is there a way to make it such the output of all commands in Bash will be automatically piped into `less -F`?

For example, if I run `cal` in Bash, I want Bash to automatically pipe it through `less -F`. In other words, I want Bash to automatically make my command `cal | less -F` instead. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure? This will break interactive commands such as CLI editors.

Comment: Why are you not able to scroll up/down in your terminal/bash?

Comment: I don't think there is any reliable way to do that -- bash would have to know which commands would try to read from stdin and which wouldn't. That should rather be a feature of the terminal emulator -- `screen` and `tmux` have something like that, though I personally never got used to it. You can use an alias or function though, so you don't have to type `| less -F` each time, e.g. `p(){ "$@" | less -F; }`

Comment: @BulletBob I was recently using a bare-bones install of FreeBSD (without X11). The console that it boots into has no scrolling. I am curious as to how others deal with the problem of losing the output of commands.

Comment: You can not scroll with shift+pg-up/down?

Comment: @BulletBob No. Shift+pg-up inserts `~`.

Comment: @user414777 Thank you for the tip about tmux. It solves my problem: https://superuser.com/questions/209437/how-do-i-scroll-in-tmux. Perhaps you should turn your entire comment into an answer.

Comment: When I last used FreeBSD, I could scroll by pressing ScrollLock and then Up/Down.

Comment: @user414777 Thank you for the tip. I have just tried using Scroll Lock in FreeBSD 12.2. It works.